# Add key value pair data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

I have a schema in Mongoose that looks like this:

```
const SocketDetailsUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String, 
    socketValue:  [{
       id: String,
       data : String     
     }], 
    isDeleted: Boolean,
    dateCreated: Date,
    updateAt: Date
});
```

I want to insert data of socketValue in key value pair in array format. Which should look like ,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a12809c7f7afb1e3626857f"),
    "userId" : "59eee19696fe6560cd54a081",
    "socketValue" :  [{"id":"5a05855b10600e4aa5b3a48e" , "value" : "123" }],[{"id":"5a0ae037a90746c249b6c1f7" , "value" : "456" }],
    "isDeleted" : false 
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is the mongoose data format.

How can i insert data in mongoose like this ?
I am also confused that how should i post data from postman to insert data in this ?

Comment: Do you need socketValue.data property to be changing ? If not it'll be ok if you rename it by `"value"`. Btw your socketValue should be only one array of objects, not multiple arrays

Comment: Did you get a change to try the below answer ? Please try providing feedback to the answer. Is something not working for you with the current answer ? It will help  understand your requirement better and gives chance to improve answer or provide new answers.

Comment: below answer is not working

Comment: @DaminiSuthar, Do you want to insert a new SocketDetailsUser document, or want to insert a new key value pair in the socketValue sub document in an existing SocketDetailsUser ?

Comment: I want to add new document data which contains key value pair value in document.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current structure is good just add `_id: false` to avoid to add auto generated `_id` in `socketValue`. like

```
socketValue:  [{
   id: String,
   data : String,
   _id: false
 }],
```

for this structure data will store like:

```
"socketValue" :  [{"id":"5a05855b10600e4aa5b3a48e" , "value" : "123" },{"id":"5a0ae037a90746c249b6c1f7" , "value" : "456" }]"
```

then you can easily update or add new `socketValue`. I think this `[{..},{..},{..}]` is the better structure instead of `[[{..}][{..}]]` this structure.

and for this structure postman request body should contain like.

```
{
    "userId" : "59eee19696fe6560cd54a081",
    "socketValue" :  [{"id":"5a05855b10600e4aa5b3a48e" , "value" : "123" },{"id":"5a0ae037a90746c249b6c1f7" , "value" : "456" }]",
    "isDeleted" : false 
}
```

and in your server side code just use like

```
var newSocket = new Socket(req.body); // assume your model name is Socket
newSocket.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your postman input data should be raw json format

```
{
    "userId" : "59eee19696fe6560cd54a081",
    "socketValue" :  [{"id":"5a05855b10600e4aa5b3a48e" , "value" : "123" },{"id":"5a0ae037a90746c249b6c1f7" , "value" : "456" }]",
    "isDeleted" : false 
}
```

Your server code

```
var insertDoc = new collectionname(details);
inserDoc.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //callback err
    } else {
        //callback result
    }
});
```